# Full screen video flickering on system with 3 4K screens

Tags: video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, 4k-resolution

I have just upgraded and got 3 4K screen for my computer. They are the screens detailed in this blog post:http://blog.codinghorror.com/our-brave-new-world-of-4k-displays/
The displays look fantastic but when playing full screen video (iPlayer, youTube, local video files) the image can flicker and sometimes have a horizontal line across it.
I fairly powerful machine:

- Intel Core i7-580K @ 3.3GHz
- 32GB Ram
- Nvidia GeForce GTX 970
- SSD
- Windows 7

Is my video card just struggling with running 3 4K screens? Do I need to upgrade that as well?

I have enabled DisplayPort 1.2 on all the monitors and have turned on 60Hz refresh rate on all 3.

Comment: It sounds like your refresh rate is low or there is a mismatch. Did you enable displayport 1.2 on the monitor (system setup) in addition to within the 970 driver settings? Does the 970 have 3 displayport outputs? Also note that Asus says: "PB279Q can support 4K UHD content at 60Hz refresh rate via DisplayPort 1.2 and Mini DisplayPort."

Comment: Yes, I do have DisplayPort 1.2 enabled on all monitors and 60Hz refresh. Updated question.